# how to echo variable in a div using php

Tags: php

In the following php code , I am trying to echo the values of $title and $desc but it doesnot show values just showing variable names. Any help will be appreciated.

```
foreach ($prod as $product) { 
    $title=$product['title'];
    $desc=$product['desc'];

    echo '
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b>$title</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#">$desc</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use double quotes, or take them outside the string - I personally always prefer the latter method, for clarity reasons. Either works.

This should do it:

```
foreach ($prod as $product) { 
    $title=$product['title'];
    $desc=$product['desc'];

    echo '
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b>'.$title.'</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#">'.$desc.'</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
    ';
}
```

Comment: This is my preference as well. Much clearer in what is going on.

Comment: The way syntax highlighting is handled points at this method as well, as it highlights the strings distinctly different from the variables this way

Comment: Echo'ing HTML with PHP is a bad idea if you expect non-programmers to work on templating etc.

Comment: @Wayne Sure, but that's hardly the discussion here.

Comment: Personally, I just think it's better practice not to echo out HTML.

Comment: I wholly agree, but the problem here was understanding that echoing variables within a string is best done using concatenation. The fact that it's HTML is irrelevant here - it could've been any string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach ($prod as $product) { 
 $title=$product['title'];
 $desc=$product['desc'];?>
  <div class="detail">
   <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
   <div class="textdetail"><p><b><?php echo $title ;?></b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#"><?php echo $desc;?></a></p>
   </div><br />
  </div>
<?php
 }?>
```

This is the best practice while using php and html together.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your variables in echo in curly brackets { }. It's a much simpler solution. Like this:

```
foreach ($prod as $product) { 
    $title=$product['title'];
    $desc=$product['desc'];

    echo "
    <div class='detail'>
    <div class='img'><img src='images/pro1.png' /></div>
    <div class='textdetail'><p><b>{$title}</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href='#'>{$desc}</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
    ";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the string, or use double quote instead of single, but in this case, you need to escape all the double quotes inside the string.

The another solution is to use heredoc:

```
echo <<<EOF
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b>$title</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#">$desc</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
EOF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to replace variable names with their content (don't forget to escape the double quotes):

```
echo "
    <div class=\"detail\">
    <div class=\"img\"><img src=\"images/pro1.png\"/></div>
    <div class=\"textdetail\"><p><b>$title</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href=\"#\">$desc</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
    ";
```

Or use string concatenation (which is faster):

```
echo '
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b>'.$title.'</b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#">'.$desc.'</a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
    ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($prod as $product):?>
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b><?=$product['title']?></b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#"><?=$product['desc']?></a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

OR

```
foreach ($prod as $product) { 
    $title=$product['title'];
    $desc=$product['desc'];

    echo '
    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b>' . $title . ' </b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#">' . $desc . ' </a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($prod as $product) { ?>

    <div class="detail">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/pro1.png"/></div>
    <div class="textdetail"><p><b><?php echo $product['title']; ?></b><br /></p>
    <p><a href="#"><?php echo $product['desc']; ?></a></p>
    </div><br />
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```